# How could I add the success and error function more easier in $promise callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have many actions in CRUD operations,

`update, create, get, delete, ..`

in each method, I have to inject idental success and error callback

How can I make it more elegant and DRY?

Thank

## update action

```
        LoanPlanService.update({
            bank_id: $scope.bank_id,
            loan_plan_id: $scope.loan_plan.id
        }, {
            loan_plan: $scope.loan_plan
        }).$promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.successMessage()
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.errorMessage(error)
        });
```

## query action

```
        LoanPlanService.query({
            bank_id: $scope.bank_id,
            loan_plan_id: $scope.loan_plan.id
        }).$promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.successMessage()
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.errorMessage(error)
        });
```

## Service

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('LoanPlanModule', [])
        .factory('LoanPlanService', ['$resource',
            function($resource, $http) {
                var LoanPlan = $resource('/api/v1/banks/:bank_id/loan_plans/:loan_plan_id', {
                    bank_id: '@bank_id',
                    loan_plan_id: '@loan_plan_id'
                }, {
                     update: { method:'PUT' },
                     create: { method: 'POST' }
                });

                return LoanPlan;
            }
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say just pass there reference in the respective callback function

```
//update
LoanPlanService.update({
    bank_id: $scope.bank_id,
    loan_plan_id: $scope.loan_plan.id
}, {
    loan_plan: $scope.loan_plan
})
.$promise.then($scope.successMessage, $scope.errorMessage);

 //query
 LoanPlanService.query({
     bank_id: $scope.bank_id,
     loan_plan_id: $scope.loan_plan.id
 }).$promise.then($scope.successMessage, $scope.errorMessage);
```

By above way `successMessage` will receive `data` parameter in it 1st parameter, where as `errorMessage` method will get `error` as in 1st parameter value as you expected.